# PHP Mailer on hosted site

Tags: html, phpmailer

Hosted website, trying to setup a mailer for the contact form but the page returns errors, Had a look in the log and found this:

PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`host5.xyz' did not match expected CN=`localhost' in /home/user/public_html/php/php-mailer/class.smtp.php on line 368

PHP Deprecated:  __autoload() is deprecated, use spl_autoload_register() instead in /home/user/public_html/php/php-mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php on line 45

Would appreciate if anyone can nudge me into the right direction, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using an old version of PHPMailer with a recent version of PHP; The current version of PHPMailer does not contain an `__autoload` function, and thus does not trigger this warning. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding, i managed to fix it today. I was using the hosts mail server instead of the domains. So i setup a mailbox for the domain admin@domainname.com and used those mail server details instead, worked right away.